# force delete and rename text file in VB6

Tags: vb6

how to force fully delete , rename and replace text file/log file in vb6. I am performing some actions on a log file and replacing original log file with a new one in the end but the application is still using the original log.

Comment: show us the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

Here is the delete

```
Sub DeleteAFile(filePath)
   Dim fso
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   fso.DeleteFile(filePath)
End Sub
```

Just mess around with the FileSystemObject class, it has methods to delete, rename, create, etc.